# How to run a command in background always?

Tags: command-line, background-process

the below command when I run from the terminal will keep posting the output to message.log

```
cf logs broker-analytics > /var/www/cfbrokerlogs/message.log
```

However, if i close my terminal it will stop working. How do i make it run in the background all the time ? Also If for any reason if it stops execution what would a good approach to check that and make sure it is always running ?

The command simply prints the log when there is any entry made.

I am on a Ubuntu server 14.04.

Comment: Do you want to run the command from the time you start it explicitly until you tell it to stop? Or do you want to run it all the time from boot?

Comment: Yes I wanted to run it all the time even on boot until I stop it myself. I tried nohup cf logs broker-analytics > /var/www/cfbrokerlogs/message.log & but that would stop on boot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `nohup` combined with `&`:

```
nohup cf logs broker-analytics > /var/www/cfbrokerlogs/message.log &
```

[The `nohup` command causes the program to ignore hangup signals (i.e. those that are sent when closing the terminal)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup), and the `&` of course runs it in the background.

If you want to make sure it's still running or kill it, you can use `ps`:

```
ps ax | grep cf logs broker-analytics
```

You should then be able to see the process ID, which you can `kill` if necessary.